# Drawing pixels in VESA graphic mode

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16, vesa

How to draw a pixel in VESA graphic mode?

I am trying interrupt `10h` function `0ch`, but it's not working. What is wrong?

(Note: I wrote this code in NASM syntax and tested it with qemu)

```
; Code:
Mov ax, 4F02h
Mov bx, 0105h ; 1024x768 pixels
Int 10h

Mov ah, 0ch ; Draw pixel function
Mov cx, 2           ; column
Mov dx, 3           ; row
Mov bh, 0    
Mov bl, 00000101b   ; colour
Int 10h

Jmp $            ; jump forever
Times 510-($-$$) db 0
Dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: Please answer this question in NASM syntax or NASM like (TASM, MASM, etc.), not GAS Syntax. Because, I am could not use GNU Assembler syntax.

Comment: @Juan: the terms you're looking for are Intel vs. AT&T syntax.  Anyway, you draw pixels by storing to video memory with `mov byte [bx], 123` (or word or whatever, depending on the pixel format you set.)  Set `ds` or `es` to the video RAM base address.

Comment: 2 downvotes? The user provided 1. What they were trying to accomplish, 2. What they tried, 3. A description of what the code SHOULD do, 4. That the code can't draw a pixel. Looking at the accepted answer, it seems what was attempted wasn't FAR off, either..? It doesn't make sense to say: "The problem is I forgot to put the color in the low byte of ax." No need to upvote, but the question and answer were an interesting problem and solution in my opinion.

Comment: @user176692: removed my downvote.  When I first read this, I missed that there was an attempt to draw a pixel as well as setting a video mode.  (I didn't know there *was* an `int 10h` function for that.  Looks like it takes more code to call it than to store to video memory, though.)  Still not a [mcve], and solved just by reading the docs.  (Except then you might not learn that storing to video RAM directly is much faster than `int 10h`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function [Int 10h/AH=0Ch](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0104.htm) should work even when using a VESA VBE mode.

Make sure to use it correctly, the pixel's colour goes into `al`.

```
;Set video mode
mov ax, 4f02h
mov bx, 105h
int 10h

;Draw pixel
mov ax, 0c09h    ;09h = Blue
mov cx, 2 
mov dx, 3     
xor bx, bx   
int 10h
```

Technically, you should use [Int 10h/AX=4F01h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0274.htm#Table81) to retrieve the video mode information, including bit 2 (*2      BIOS output supported*) of the *mode attributes* field, to check if the BIOS functions will work.

Writing a high-resolution image using the BIOS function could be too slow, it may be worth investing in writing directly to a linear or windowed frame buffer.
Writing to a linear framebuffer will probably require using [the unreal mode](https://wiki.osdev.org/Unreal_Mode), it's possible to avoid that by using a windowed framebuffer.
This, besides being slower, is also more cumbersome.

Here is a very simple program that fills 30 rows with a horrible shade of grey.
**Note** that I stripped all the checks for the sake of compactness and clarity, I made *a lot* of assumptions to avoid making some math.
This is a bad practice, I used it only for *prototyping*.
I strongly encourage you to read the full information returned by `Int 10h/AX=4F01h` and use that information to select the correct window, do the right padding and calculations.

```
BITS 16

ORG 100h

mov ax, ds
mov es, ax 

;Set video mode
mov ax, 4f02h
mov bx, 105h
int 10h

;Get video mode info
mov ax, 4f01h
mov cx, 105h
mov di, modeInfo 
int 10h

;Assume first window is valid 
mov ax, WORD [es:modeInfo + 08h]
mov es, ax

;Example of how to change the window 
mov ax, 4f05h
xor bx, bx
mov dx, 5       ;This is granularity units
int 10h

xor di, di 
mov al, 0f1h
mov cx, 3*1024*20

rep stosb

;Wait for key
xor ax, ax
int 16h

;Restore DOS text mode
mov ax, 0003h
int 10h

;Exit
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h

modeInfo    TIMES 256 db 0
```

This is in NASM syntax, I usually use TASM (out of affection) for DOS programs but this time I was in a hurry.
The result is

[image: A grey band in the, more or less, middle of a black screen]

Remember that each scanline can, in general, be padded (the size of a scanline is returned in the video mode information).
For a 1024 pixel wide scanline, with 3x8bpp we have 3072 bytes/scanline, since this is divisible by 4, no padding is *likely* to happen.
The window start address is given in the granularity unit (also found in the video mode information), the total framebuffer is 1024x768x3 bytes = 2.25 MiB, assuming no padding.
The window size is also found in the video mode information.

All this is enough to write to the framebuffer.
A linear framebuffer is easier to handle (padding is still an aspect to consider) once the unreal mode has been set up.